# How to set an HTML block as a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The website has a list of thumbnails,containing people's name,ID,and photo,if click it will pop up the detail, but when I click the photo or text it do not respond, only work when I click the blank space:

```
<ul>
<li class="profile" id="0000">
   <img src="photo1.jpg" alt="thumbnail"/>
   <p>Name</p>
   <p>0000</p>
</li>
<li class="profile" id="0001">
   <img src="photo2.jpg" alt="thumbnail"/>
   <p>Name</p>
   <p>0001</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

and add event listener by jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".profile").click(function(event){});
});
```

How to make the li block act like one button (display:block doesn't work)

Comment: You don't need any changes it should work as desired; also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yh5uu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an 'a' tag to wrap your html content

```
<li class="profile" id="0000">
    <a>
       <img src="photo1.jpg" alt="thumbnail"/>
       <p>Name</p>
       <p>0000</p>
    </a>
    </li>
```

Then use,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".profile a").click(function(event){});
});
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CpEJc/1/)

Comment: I finally found the problem, my code doesn't work is because of I use  $(event.target).attr("id") to get detail, but when I click the text or img, the event.target do not have the ID attribute. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you attach the click even handler to the elements selected by class like that it does just that. Your code works; See this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/codetantra/xbAMJ/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a particular reason for using list items for this but if it's necessary then try this, taking the classes out of the `li` elements:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#" class="profile" id="0000"><img src="photo1.jpg" alt="thumbnail"/></a>
      <p class="hide"><span>Name</span><br /><span>0000</span</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#" class="profile" id="0001"><img src="photo2.jpg" alt="thumbnail"/></a>
      <p class="hide"><span>Name</span><br /><span>0001</span</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.profile').click(function($e){
      $e.preventDefault();
      $('p.hide').toggle();
   })
})
```

Then just in the CSS add:

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .profile{
        width : 100px;
        list-style : none;
        cursor : pointer;
        background : #acce3c;
        border : 1px solid gray;
    }

    .profile:active
    {
        background : #beeb5c;
    }
</style>
```